# Determine whether this set of vectors is linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, homogeneous-equation

By using appropriate identities, where required, determine if the following set of vectors in F(-infinity, infinity) is linearly dependent: $6, 3(\sin^2(x)), 2(\cos^2(x))$.

So I try to multiple by scalars but since there is little to work with I am stuck on how to set up a matrix to find the solution to a homogeneous system of the scalars. I know that sin squared x plus cos squared x is 1. I believe that is the way to do it. Hmmmm.... Not used to this kind of problem though did the other ones guess I don't understand the whole idea perfectly.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to just give it a hard look and come up with some scalars:

$-1\cdot 6 + 2\cdot(3\sin^2(x)) + 3\cdot(2\cos^2(x))=9$.

My thought process was "how can I find a common 'denominator' so that the $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ can be replaced by $1$?"  That you had $6$ as a constant function, and that it is $2\cdot 3$, I think sort of gives away that this how you were intended to find a linear dependence.

Comment: i guess that's a way but i need to know how to do it via the standard procedure

Comment: I don't know that you mean by "the" standard procedure, but try replacing $\cos^2(x)$ with $1-\sin^2(x)$ in the third vector and see if that helps you apply it.

Comment: let's see not a bad thought

Comment: 6a + 3b(sin sq x) + c(2 - 2 sin sq x)

Comment: nothing is ringing

Comment: You should be able, in that last equation you wrote, to find $a,b,c$, not all zero, that make the expression identically zero.

Comment: If you write this in terms of $1$ and $\sin^2 x$ (i.e., $(6a+2c)\cdot 1 + (3b-2c)\cdot\sin^2 x=0$), hopefully it's clear how to solve for $a,b,c$.

Comment: So, Newton, are we OK now?